# Joomla package installation error

Tags: joomla

Currently I am using Joomla 1.5.2 ver, I try to upgrade it by Admin tools but when I try to install package I got this error:

```
It was not possible to copy the selected file.
JInstaller::install: Failed to copy file: /tmp/install_4f1ea249ef5dc/media/css to /content/HostingPlus/f/r/website.com/web/new/media/com_admintools/css
        JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/es-ES.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'es-ES' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/it-IT.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'it-IT' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/pt-BR.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'pt-BR' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/pt-PT.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'pt-PT' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/de-DE.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'de-DE' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/nb-NO.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'nb-NO' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/sv-SE.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'sv-SE' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/el-GR.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'el-GR' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/fr-FR.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'fr-FR' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/nl-NL.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'nl-NL' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/pl-PL.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'pl-PL' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/ro-RO.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'ro-RO' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/et-EE.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'et-EE' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/hu-HU.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'hu-HU' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/zh-TW.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'zh-TW' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/sk-SK.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'sk-SK' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/fi-FI.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'zh-TW' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/th-TH.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'th-TH' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/ru-RU.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'ru-RU' has not been installed or does not exist.
    JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/lt-LT.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'lt-LT' has not been installed or does not exist.
```

Please suggest what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Install the language package for 'bs-BA'?

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/jtranslation/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=2344